# How to perform command substitution before brace expansion?

Tags: bash, command-substitution, brace-expansion

I would like to perform command substitution before brace expansion, but couldn't:

```
$ ls {$(seq -s , 13 20)}.pdf
ls: cannot access {13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}.pdf: No such file or directory
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to use the `eval` shell builtin:

```
$ eval ls {$(seq -s , 13 20)}.pdf
```

Where `eval` takes the arguments passed to it:

`ls {$(seq -s , 13 20)}.pdf`

and concatenates them together into a single command:

```
ls {13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}.pdf
```

which is then read and executed by the shell.

```
$ eval ls {$(seq -s , 13 20)}.pdf
13.pdf  14.pdf  15.pdf  16.pdf  17.pdf  18.pdf  19.pdf  20.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried

```
ls $(seq -f %.0f.pdf 13 20 )
```

- `-f` gives the format string
- `.0f` for 0 decimal digit float
- `.pdf` obvious

(and you know about $( ) syntax)